# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application Running jar file on other computer

Tags: java, javafx, jar, jvm, noclassdeffounderror

When I run my application in the IntelliJ IDE, it runs my program and there are no issues. My problem occurs when building the jar artifact and running that jar file on another computer. The jar file runs as expected on the same pc that I have been developing the project on. Did I configure anything incorrectly?

Modules
[image]

Artifacts
[image]

[image]

VM Args
[image]

```
--module-path "D:/openjfx-18.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web
```

I've tried including the projects with maven and including downloaded jar files from maven. I've tried different SDK versions as well as using liberica sdk. I've added vm options. I've re-made the project and copied my class files+resources. This is becoming a frustrating problem. I've looked at other answers for this problem but nothing seems to solve it.

If I open the jar file and look at its contents, the javafx files are not present.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you install the SDK on the other computer?

Comment: I get the same error message after installing the jdk. Both java19 jdk and liberica. I've checked my environment variables + restart and still nothing. Since the libraries were not found in the jar file, what would cause this file to run as intended on the pc I developed it on but not another pc? With the way the project has been configured, should these not be included in the jar file? Only one library is included when viewing the jar file: jaiimageio. Why would the rest be left out when they were similarly included?

Comment: My advice is not to make a jar, but instead make a zip of a jlink image or use jpackage to create an installer.

Comment: @jewelsea's advice is sound. In the interim: What happens if you specify the `module-path` and `add-modules` options (shown in your VM Args) in your `java` command on the other computer?

Comment: Wow. Jpackage solved my problem. It was super easy to create the installer. Thank you, jewels! Tbh I didn't think about using a tool other than IntelliJ to deploy my application. I did try adding the modules to the jar file using cmd before posting here. I can't remember exactly what message was in the output but it was an error with --module-path. Thank you both for the support!